# R - Can I pass a command line argument using Rscript to a query using RMySQL dbConnect?

Tags: r, rmysql, rscript

I am trying to pass a site id argument as an integer from Rscript on the command line to a SQL statement inside dbConnect using RMySQL. However I am getting an error
"Error in mysqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused arguments ("3", " AND `name` = 'HVAC #1 Supply Temp' ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 15;")"

```
user@debian:~$ Rscript deltaTsql.R 3
```

is what I am running from the command prompt.

My script is

```
library(RMySQL,quietly=TRUE)
library(rjson,quietly=TRUE)

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(length(args))
as.integer(args[1])

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="password", dbname="dbname", host="host")

r1.dat <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT `site_id`,`name`,`value`,`created` FROM `table` WHERE `site_id` = ", args[1], " AND `name` = 'HVAC #1 Supply Temp' ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 15;")
r2.dat <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT `site_id`,`name`,`value`,`created` FROM `table` WHERE `site_id` =", args[1], " AND `name` = 'HVAC #1 Return Temp' ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 15;")

r <- merge(r1.dat,r2.dat,by=c("created","site_id"))

r$supplytemp <- (r$value.x*(9/5)+32)
r$returntemp <- (r$value.y*(9/5)+32)

r$deltaT <- (r$returntemp-r$supplytemp)
deltaT <- r$deltaT

deltaTcheck <- function(deltaT) {
if (deltaT>25) {
return(1)
}
else if (deltaT<10) {
return(-1)
}
else {
return(0)
}
}

deltaTout <- vapply(deltaT, deltaTcheck, numeric(1))
deltaTjson <- toJSON(deltaTout)
deltaTjson
```

I want to be able to pass the same argument to two separate SQL statements so that I can grab both separately before merging them on the site id. Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to `paste()` together your SQL statement into a single character value

```
r1.dat <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT `site_id`,`name`,`value`,`created` 
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE `site_id` = ", args[1], " AND `name` = 'HVAC #1 Supply Temp' 
    ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 15;"))
```

Comment: It would be safer to use a parameterised query